# Only reductive Lie algebras have faithful irreducible representations

Tags: lie-algebras

Theorem 19.1b of Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* states that if a complex Lie algebra has a finite-dimensional non-trivial (Update: faithful) irreducible representation, then it is reductive. Unfortunately, a proof is not readable. Could you explain the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Theorem $19.1 (b)$ says something different, namely the following: if a Lie algebra $L$ of linear transformations in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ acts irreducibly on $V$ then $L$ is reductive with $0$ or $1$-dimensional center. The proof relies on *Lie's Theorem* showing that the solvable radical $rad(L)$ of $L$ consists only of the center. But a Lie algebra $L$ which satisfies $Rad(L)=Z(L)$, or $L=[L,L]\oplus Z(L)$ is reductive. This has been explained on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172620/an-alternative-definition-of-reductive-lie-algebra).

Comment: It is probably also worth pointing out that version of the theorem the OP stated is quite far from being true.

Comment: So the difference is that only the image is reductive, that is, does the word faithful makes the statement true?