# real Lie algebra with positive Killing form is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over the real numbers with positive definite Killing form. Why is $L=\{0\}$?

As a hint we should have a look at Gram-Schmidt orthonormalisation.

Everything I tried failed so far, so the usual 'What do I have so far' field is left empty. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ be a real Lie algebra with positive definite Killing form. Its Killing
form $\kappa$ defines an inner product on $L$. Hence $L$ is reductive. Thus the
quotient $L/Z(L)$ is semisimple. So, the Killing form is negative definite of 
$L/Z(L)$. Therefore, this Killing form is both positive definite and negative definite, it follows that $L/Z(L) = {0}$. So we get $L = Z(L)=\ker(\kappa)$. But $\kappa$ is non-degenerate since it’s positive definite. It follows that $L= {0}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't follow. I have not heard of the term 'reductive' and how this is related to semisimplicity. Do you know how to use the given hint?

Comment: Reductive is very closely related to semisimple, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172620/an-alternative-definition-of-reductive-lie-algebra).

Comment: Gram-Schmidt gives the Iwasawa decomposition $G=KAN$ for the Lie group. The Lie algebra of a compact Lie group is reductive.

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you!

Comment: I have several questions: 1. Why killing form on L/Z(L) is negative definite?   2. Why the induced Killing form on L/Z(L) is positive definite? 3. Why ker(k)=Z(L)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Dietrich has said, the Killing form $\kappa$ defines an positive-definite inner product on the Lie algebra $L$, which is also $ad$-invariant. A Lie algebra is a compact Lie algebra iff it admits an $ad$-invariant inner product, which is our case. But a compact Lie algebra's Killing form must be negative-definite. Thus $\kappa$ is both negative- and positive-definite. So we conclude that $L$ must be trivial.