# About some details about the proof that real Lie algebra with positive Killing form is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

In the post about proving that real Lie algebra with positive Killing form is zero: [real Lie algebra with positive Killing form is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297705/real-lie-algebra-with-positive-killing-form-is-zero):

> Let $L$ be a real Lie algebra with positive definite Killing form. Its Killing
>   form $\kappa$ defines an inner product on $L$. Hence $L$ is reductive. Thus the
>   quotient $L/Z(L)$ is semisimple. So, the Killing form is negative definite of 
>   $L/Z(L)$. Therefore, this Killing form is both positive definite and negative definite, it follows that $L/Z(L) = {0}$. So we get $L = Z(L)=\ker(\kappa)$. But $\kappa$ is non-degenerate since it’s positive definite. It follows that $L= {0}$.

I am confused with the following gaps:

1. Why killing form on $L/Z(L)$ is negative definite?
2. Why the induced Killing form on $L/Z(L)$ is positive definite?

And is there any relation with the fact that $\mathfrak{g}$ is real?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I admit I don't immediately understand this step either... certainly semisimple Lie algebras do not have negative-definite Killing form in general.

Here is another argument: if $\mathfrak{g}$ has positive-definite Killing form $\kappa$, let $x_1,...,x_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and write $[x_i,x_j] = \sum_k a_{ijk} x_k$ with $a_{ijk} \in \mathbb{R}$. The invariance $\kappa([x,y],z) = \kappa(x,[y,z])$ implies $a_{ijk} + a_{ikj} = 0$. Therefore $$\kappa(x_i,x_i) = \mathrm{tr}( \mathrm{ad}(x_i) \cdot \mathrm{ad}(x_i)) = \sum_{j,k} a_{ijk}a_{ikj} = - \sum_{j,k} a_{ijk}^2 \le 0,$$ contradiction.

Comment: Could you please show how the invariance implies the "skew-symmetry"?

Comment: $a_{ijk} = K([x_{i},x_{j}],x_{k}) = K(x_{i}, [x_{j}, x_{k}]) = -K([x_{i}, x_{k}], x_{j}) = -a_{ikj}$

Answer (score 1):

1. The Killing form on $L/Z(L)$ is negative definite because as $L$ is reductive, the corresponding Lie Group such that $Lie(G)=L$ is compact. Then by Weyl unitary trick, any representation $(\rho,V)$ of $G$ is unitary. That is, $\rho(G) \subset U(V)$. So we get $\rho_*(L) \subset \mathfrak{u}(V)$.
   Now because the trace form of $\mathfrak{u}(V)$, $(x,y)=tr(\rho(x),\rho(y))$ is negative definite, then take $\rho=ad$ we get the negative definite Killing form.
2. The value of Killing form on $L/Z(L)$ is sum of Killing form on $Z(L)$ and $L$. Since the Killing form on $Z(L)$ is just $0$ then they must coincide.