# Skew-symmetry of $ad(X)$ in real Lie algebras

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Suppose we have real Lie algebras. What I want to show is $[x_i, x_j]=a_{ijk}x_k=-a_{ikj}x_j$. I have seen some hints from other questions that in order to prove it one should use the Killing form identity with $ad(X)$ but I cannot explicitly proove it. Can anyone show? Thank you!

[About some details about the proof that real Lie algebra with positive Killing form is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546778/about-some-details-about-the-proof-that-real-lie-algebra-with-positive-killing-f)
This is link to the other question. I am sorry for pasting it like that but am having some troubles making the hyperlink.

Comment: Where does the free suffix k in the last $a_{ikj}x_j$ come from?

Comment: $[x_{i},x_{k}]=a_{ikj}x_{j}$ It is meant to be like that.

Comment: Does not compute. What are the elements $x_i$ here? Basis elements of some Lie algebra? Why would there be only a single basis element $x_k$ in the formula for the Lie bracket $[x_i,x_j]$? That is certainly not true in general. Are you assuming some summation convention? Are the coefficients $a_{ijk}$ **defined** via the relation $[x_i,x_j]=\sum_k a_{ijk} x_k$, and you want to prove that $a_{ijk}=a_{ikj}$ for all $i,j,k$? Where's the skew-symmetry? We would expect to have a minus sign somewhere :-)

Comment: You are right about the minus sign. Will edit it in the question. I want to prove it only for basis element. If it is true for basis it will be true in general because of the linearity.