Bounds on the norm of Lie Bracket with respect to Killing Form
If we have a real Lie algebra $(V, [,])$ then the Lie bracket is a bilinear map
$$
[, ]: V \times V \to V
$$
Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional, this map is bounded and so, for any choice of norm, there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$
\|[v, w]\| \leq C\|v\|\|w\|.
$$
If $V$ is a compact semisimple Lie algebra then there is a natural choice of norm given by the Killing form. If we pick this norm, can we say anything about the optimal values of $C$? For example, it could be the case that with the Killing form
$$
\|[v, w]\| \leq \|v\|\|w\|,
$$
but it may also be possible to construct examples where $C$ is arbitrarily large.

"[...] then there is a natural choice of norm given by the Killing form" -- how so? The Killing form is basically never positive definite (if the ground field is $\mathbb R$), cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2546778/96384; and if the ground field is $\mathbb C$, it is not even sesquilinear (the Killing form is always bilinear). So it's not an inner product.

Ah, I'm unsure of the correct lie algebra terminology - I want to restrict to real Lie algebras where the killing form is negative definite (I should have made this more clear in the question).

Then you need compact semisimple (real) Lie algebras. You can (and should) edit that in the question.

Thanks for editing. Now why don't you try the easiest example $\mathfrak{su}_2$ (a three-dimensional compact Lie algebra) and share the results?

$su(2) \cong \mathbb R^3$ with the Lie bracket given by the cross product. The negative of the killing form is 2 times the euclidean inner product. With the euclidean inner product, the formula for the cross product in terms of $\sin$ gives $| w \wedge v | < |v||w|$. Hence with respect the the killing form norm $|v\wedge v| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|v||w|$.
